# Static or dynamic class?

Tags: c#

A followup to this post: [Need advice on design/structure of a game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16552866/need-advice-on-design-structure-of-a-game)

I have `Game.cs`, which essentially holds my gamestate. All necessary variables will be included here when everything is said and done to make saving, loading, and starting a new game easier. My question is this: Should this class be static or dynamic? I tried dynamic, but I can't figure out where to instantiate it properly. At the moment, `Game.cs` is instantiated when a button click event fires in a Windows Form, but afterward is treated as a local variable and it can't be accessed elsewhere. Is there a way to instantiate it globally? Or in this case is `static` the way to go?

Comment: BTW, `dynamic` isn't really the word you are looking for.  A `Dynamic` object is one whose variables and methods are established at runtime, not compile time.  Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/241339/when-to-use-static-classes-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have the `Game` *class* be an instance class: everything should be instance fields/properties/methods, not static.

Within your game, you should have just one *instance* of the Game class. You could pass it around to all of the other classes, or you could just make it global, by making it a public static public field on some class.

Answer (score 3):

As a rule of thumb, static classes/methods should be stateless. If you want to have your data accessible from anywhere, you should go for the Singleton-Pattern.

```
public class Game
{
    private static Game instance;
    public static Game Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                instance = new Game();
            }
            return instance;
        }
    }

    private Game()
    {
    }

    private int someData;

    public string SomeMethod()
    {
    }

    // ...
}
```

Then, access it in your code like so:

```
string myString = Game.Instance.SomeMethod();
```

Comment: I would consider it common courtesy for the one who downvoted my answer to at least tell me what was disliked about it.

Comment: I can hazard a guess: some folks consider Singleton a bit of an anti-pattern, akin to global variables.

Comment: Fair enough. A damn side better than the alternative, though ;)

Comment: They're also difficult to do properly: http://csharpindepth.com/articles/general/singleton.aspx

Comment: Your original answer wasn't one, and it ended with "Example to follow". I downvoted you for starting with a placeholder instead of an actual answer.

Comment: Actually, yes it was. I did not post "Hold on, answering" or something, I just did not give the example of a singleton pattern. The answer itself was - IMHO - completely valid.