# Instantiating a class with outside accessiblity from a method/event

Tags: c#

I have a class `Game` which cannot be made static for serialization purposes. I would like to instantiate `Game` from a method and have the new instance accessible elsewhere in the code.

If I try this:

```
    public void btnNewGame_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Game game = new Game();
    }
```

The new instance is unusable outside of this method. Is there any way to instantiate `Game` within the method and have the instance accessible elsewhere? Or are there any workarounds? The thing is that I don't want `Game` to be instantiated before this button is clicked.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Why not have a static Game _game outside of the method and instantiate Game inside the method and make _game = game.  This way you would have a static variable which holds an instance of Game.

Comment: Consider moving the "serializable" properties of `Game` to a separate `GameState` object. Serialize/deserialize the `GameState` and have a method `Game.LoadFromState(GameState)` which would read/assign whatever data is applicable. This way the centralized `Game` class can be static (if that's what you want) and can store non-serializable content; perhaps more importantly, the saving/loading mechanism can be abstracted to store/read from different locations (database, file system, etc.) or better maintain backward compatibility to slightly older versions of  your game.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair Thanks for the tip. I'll go ahead and do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The singleton pattern with lazy instantiation is your friend here.

Check out [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16553554/static-or-dynamic-class/16553611#16553611) for an example.

Comment: Can Singletons be serialized without any problems?

Comment: Yes. A singleton is just a regular class with regular fields, only with magic that makes sure that there is only one instance of it, and that this instance is accessible anywhere in the code. :)

Comment: I'll play around with this. I suppose my only concern is deserialization if the instance is already active (IE, if the the player loads an old save from the pause screen). We'll see, I suppose.

Comment: In that case, you would have to write a specialized setter that not just anyone can call, I guess. By the way, the pattern I gave is NOT threadsafe.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a static property that returns the one and only `Game` object that exists. For example:

```
public class Game
{
    private static Game instance;
    public static Game Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
                instance = new Game();
            return instance;
        }
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
Game theOneAndOnlyGame = Game.Instance;
```

---

Or, if you can't change the `Game` class:

```
public static class MyGameEngine
{
    private static Game game;
    public static Game Game
    {
        get
        {
            if (game == null)
                game = new Game();
            return game;
        }
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
Game theOneAndOnlyGame = MyGameEngine.Game;
```